# Jquery unobtrusive validation works very slow ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have ASP.Net MVC3 application in which there is an partial page which loads a huge load of html controls(around Count=980) which has it validation assigned to them.

JQuery Unobtrusive validation is taking a long while to validate the form with above controls. Its hitting the performance of the application. Is there a way to improve, how the validation is done on the elements of DOM?

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue. We found no easy way to improve the performance.

I had to disable unobtrusive and client side validation for the page. Form was taking 10 + second to render and it only had an id and checkbox per item for about 1000 items. After we removed client side and unobtrusive page load was about 1 sec

We just validated on the controller.

You can use these page level helpers

```
Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(false);
```

Comment: Woa ! I am curious, what kind of functionality has a thousand inputs in the same page?

Comment: Feature demanded client. Wanted to able to bulk confirm in an admin section. Didn't want paging and didn't want Ajax. So a giant form it was.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today. I realized that there was significant slowdown on one of my large lists. There is an option to view all, and in that view there is a form per line for deleting items. `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` was destroying this page on load. When it was removed, the load was only 2s.  Many of the forms needed no validation, but some still did.  As a result, i looked in the code for the file and found this:

```
parse: function (selector) {
        /// <summary>
        /// Parses all the HTML elements in the specified selector. It looks for input elements decorated
        /// with the [data-val=true] attribute value and enables validation according to the data-val-*
        /// attribute values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selector" type="String">Any valid jQuery selector.</param>
        $(selector).find(":input[data-val=true]").each(function () {
            $jQval.unobtrusive.parseElement(this, true);
        });

        $("form").each(function () {//THIS IS THE OFFENDING CODE
            var info = validationInfo(this);
            if (info) {
                info.attachValidation();
            }
        });
    }
```

I realized that I would need to somehow alter that call, but still retain functionality. What I ended up doing was to mark all of my forms that I did not want to go through this parse method with `class="skipValid"`. Then, in the source code, I made this change:

```
$("form:not(.skipValid)").each(function () {
```

and I had the best of both worlds.